# Build a url with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using retrofit to access data about tv channels.
The url that i have is this:

```
http://ott.online.meo.pt/catalog/v7/Channels?UserAgent=AND&$filter=substringof(%27MEO_Mobile%27,AvailableOnChannels)%20and%20IsAdult%20eq%20false&$orderby=ChannelPosition%20asc&$inlinecount=allpages
```

In Retrofit.Builder() i put "the main url" (`http://ott.online.meo.pt`) and in interface `Endpoint` the rest of url. 
I do this, but i don't kwon how put the complet url

```
interface Endpoint {
    @Headers("User-Agent: AND")
    @GET("catalog/v7/Channels" )
    fun getChannels() : Call<SerializeChannels>
}
```

Comment: Retrofit has pretty good documentation on how to add query params to the URL: https://square.github.io/retrofit/. You can also just use the entire URL string as the argument to `@GET` if the query params are not supposed to be dynamic.

Comment: And it’s correct to use the entire URL string as an argument to @GET?

Comment: According to the docs - it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your retrofit client :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://ott.online.meo.pt/")
        .build();
```

You can define endpoint in multiple way:

Following is hard codded way:

```
interface Endpoint {
    @GET("catalog/v7/Channels?UserAgent=AND&filter=substringof('MEO_Mobile',AvailableOnChannels)&IsAdult=false&orderby=ChannelPosition asc&inlinecount=allpages" )
    fun getChannels() : Call<SerializeChannels>
}
```

You can also use Query parameter as follows:

```
interface Endpoint {
   @GET("catalog/v7/Channels")
   fun getChannels( @Query("UserAgent") String agent, @Query("filter") String filters,@Query("IsAdult") String isAdult,@Query("orderby") String sort,@Query("inlinecount") String count) : Call<SerializeChannels>
}
```